# Pivot Sql with no aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I learned I can't pivot text without aggregation max() & min().

I am trying to figure out a workaround but the answers to similar questions are sailing over my head. would anyone have tips to workaround that?

**data table:**

| pax | codex | mis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dog1 | hair | 10 |
| dog1 | face | 10 |
| dog1 | eye | 5 |
| dog1 | smell | 7 |
| dog1 | yellow | 7 |
| dog1 | green | 8 |
| dog1 | blue | 9 |
| dog1 | tan | 10 |

**desired output:**

| pax | 10 | 10 | 5 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dog1 | hair | face | eye | smell | yellow | green | blue | tan |

**actual outcome:**

| pax | 10 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dog1 | hair | eye | smell | green | blue |

I used this code:

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(mis) + ',' FROM (select distinct mis from #dd) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
   select   pax,codex,mis from #dd


) src
pivot 
(
    max(codex) for mis in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select
  pax,
  concat(mis, '-', rn) as mis_new,
  codex
from (
    Select
      pax,
      mis,
      row_number() over (partition by pax, mis 
          order by mis ) rn 
    from table
) t
pivot (
  max(codex) for (
    mis_new in ('10-1','10-2', '5-1','7-1','7-2','8-1','9-1','10-3')
) pvt
```

Comment: recieved this error:   The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.

Comment: Check now if it works

Comment: thank you for the responses. I am using MS SQL maybe that is why. i have recieved incorrect syntax error near pivot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like standard conditional aggregation over a row-number would serve better:

```sql
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) =
(
  SELECT CONCAT(',MIN(CASE WHEN mis = ', QUOTENAME(mis, ''''), ' AND rn = ', rn, ' THEN codex END) ', QUOTENAME(mis))
  FROM (
      SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pax ORDER BY mis) rn
      FROM dd
  ) as tmp
  GROUP BY mis, rn
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)');

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT
  pax' + @cols + '
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pax ORDER BY mis) rn
    FROM dd
) dd
GROUP BY pax;
';

PRINT @query; --for testing

EXEC sp_executesql
  @query;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3758c31c61d0488b2265b7e109f95f25)

> Note the use of `FOR XML` to aggregate. Variable coalescing should not be used, due to unpredictability.

Comment: that worked beautifully, thanks for all your help everyone! I had not learned of the parition function yet. I have a lot to learn.